# Eloquent query not working

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, relationships

I have a many to many relationship between users and categories. In a third table, I have a field called category_id to reference what category each record belongs to. I am setting up a system where by once a user logs in, I want them to see records that has category_id of the categories they've selected when registering.

My code is shown below
I have this relationship setup in users model,

```
public function categories()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Category');
}
```

and also this

```
public function userCats()
{
    return $this->categories()->get();
}
```

in the categories table i have this relationship setup

```
public function users()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\User');
}
```

in my 3rd Table controller i have the following code

```
if(Auth::check()){
    $servo  = Jumong::postOnly()->whereIn('category_id', Auth::user()->userCats())->get();
} else {
    $servo = Jumong::all()->where('type','P');
}
dd($servo);
```

The problem is that the below part,

```
Auth::user()->userCats()
```

It returns only the last 2 records in Jumong table and there are more than that.
If I replace it with an array, it will return the right results.

Any ideas on what I am missing?

Comment: Look at the laravel docs for using a pivot table

Answer (score 2):

It doesn't work because whereIn expects an array of ids whereas
 Auth::user()->userCats() returns a collection of categories. 
You can still doing something like.

`Auth::user()->categories->pluck('id')`